# Initialize object with lambda function in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I would like to know if the following scenario is possible.

I have a class `A` which has some data members, one of them being a container (let's assume a simple array).

Now to the constructors of `A`, I'd like to pass a lambda function to initialize the data members of the class. 
I want the user to be given the ability to write his own initialization routine and have it applied on the class.

For example, consider this constructor of `A` which takes 2 arguments. 
The first as the size of the array and the second, a lambda function.

```c
A(std::function<void (self_type)> f) {
    f(*this);
}
```

Now I'd create an object as follows:

```c
A a([](A a) {
    //do something here to initialize array and data members
});
```

This way, the user is given the ability to perform his own initialization rather than using the constructors or other fill functions offered by the class.

Is this possible using some trickery? It'd be even better if I somehow could use `this` inside the lambda function.

For example -

```
A a([]() {
    //do something here to initialize array and data members
    this->_n = 100; // where _n is some data member.
});
```

Any possible solution is welcome!

Comment: A lambda function can do anything any other function can do, some would even say they have more functionality because of variable capture

Comment: Yes, but I would not be able to access the private members of the class. Is there a way by which I can get access to it? 
Also I would not be able to use `this` inside the lambda function (considering the current scenario. I'd have to pass `*this` explicitly in the function call (which is the only way I can see for now).

Comment: Then you can either use setters and getters, or have the user pass lambdas to another function that does it

Comment: What I'd like to do is access the member directly. Its just during the time of initialization of the object. 
Getters and setters may not be present all the time for all data members (may be restricted). I have my own class in place, all I'd like to do is offer an initialization mechanism directly to the user. Would that be possible?

Comment: How about passing the array to the lambda function?

Comment: @VaughnCato how can you pass the array if it's private

Comment: @aaronman: A's constructor can access private members, including passing them to another function.

Comment: @VaughnCato ok I didn't realize you meant to also pass the lambda to the constructor, that was the solution I suggested

Comment: Why prefer having the user pass an initialization function rather than having the user pass the values for the data members?

Comment: @VaughnCato I think you didn't get my problem. I have some containers which I want to initialize using some algo the user likes. Hence I want to extend the initialization mechanism to the user so that he can write his own algo and initialize the object rather than having the object's containers filled with some default value and later being assigned (through a loop) using the user's algo.

The result of such a mechanism gives the user the ability to have is object fully ready at initialization. Thus combining two steps (initialize with default value and assign using algo) into one.

Comment: It just seems like a strange thing to want to do.  Typically in that scenario, I would expect the user to build the values however they like before creating an `A`, and then pass those values to `A`'s constructor. Maybe an example of where what you are proposing would help would be useful.

Comment: Your explanation of your problem in your previous comment makes no sense, because Vaughn's solution solves that problem better than your solution.  With your solution, the objects would be initialized by their constructors, and then reassigned by the user's algorithm.  If you just let the user pass objects into the constructor, and then move the arguments into member objects, the object is "fully ready at initialization".

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if a class keeps members private, it enforces an invariant over the state of those members. If you let J. Random User poke at your privates you don't know that he will maintain that invariant. So I'm not sure if this is design-wise a good idea.

That said, you can achieve something like this by putting all relevant data members in a private base class as public members:

```
struct A_base {
  int something;
  std::string some_other_thing;
};

class A : private A_base {
public:
  A(std::function<void(A_base&)> f) { f(*this); }
  template <typename Function>
  A(Function&& f) { std::forward<Function>(f)(*this); }
};
```

This provides the required access to the user function, but obviously without the syntactic ability to use `this`.

Comment: This does give me some ideas. Although I'd prefer not incorporate the design as is.